# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.datasets' has no attribute 'load_titanic'

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, attributeerror, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to load the file titanic and I face the following problem. My code is:

```
from sklearn import datasets
titanic = datasets.load_titanic()
```

I get the following:

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.datasets' has no attribute 'load_titanic'
```

While I can load another file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#toy-datasets), there is no toy dataset `load_titanic()` for the current stable version (`scikit-learn v0.19.1`) - which version are you using? You get the version via `sklearn.__version__`.

From the docs, there are the following toy datasets available:

```
load_boston()
load_iris()
load_diabetes(
load_digits()
load_linnerud()
load_wine()
load_breast_cancer()
```

Maybe your tutorial is outdated?

Answer (score 1):

sklearn v0.20.2 does not have `load_titanic` either.   You can easily use:

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic=sns.load_dataset('titanic')
```

But please take note that this is only a subset of the data.  The total number of passengers of the Titanic is 2223 (or 2224), and the number of survivors is 706.  Please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Titanic).

Answer (score 0):

The titanic dataset is available in sklearn now, via `fetch_openml`:

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.fetch_openml(name='titanic', version=1)
```

I'm using `1.3.2`.